# An introductory book on graph transformation algorithms

Tags: algorithms, graphs, books

I am looking for a preferably modern book on graph transformation algorithms. I am really interested into general approaches not on mathematical proofs and rigor notations. The easier the read, the better is the book.

Comment: "Good" is a matter of opinion, and opinion questions are not well-suited here; see our [help/dont-ask].  It would help to elaborate on what you mean by "graph transformation algorithms" and why you think books on that topic exist. Book recommendation questions are hard to make fit the Stack Exchange, but what works is to identify a set of requirements, and identify what books you've considered and why you've rejected them.  If you just want an idea and haven't done any research yet, then I suggest you check Amazon.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by graph transformation algorithms?

Comment: I have edited the question and removed the word "good". I hope the question is clearer now. I am looking for algorithms that transform graphs based on some declarative rules. There are multiple approaches to this problem and I need an introductory book on the matter that focus on the algorithms rather than the math and proofs behind them.